# Is Angular ng-repeat filter result accessible?

Tags: angularjs

I am successfully using ng-repeat and its filter and orderBy functions

```
<div ng-repeat="center in centers  | filter: subjectName | orderBy:[\'name\',\'parent']">'
```

However when user decides to print/download the "centers" filtered and ordered by angular, the printing method fails because it knows only the original unsorted unfilterd array. Is there a way to capture the object resulted by the filtered/orderBy angular methods so I could use it directly in my printing method?

```js
<div ng-repeat="center in centers  | filter: subjectName | orderBy:[\'name\',\'parent']">'
    '<span>{{center.name}</span>'+
</div>
....
// what I have so far
<li><a ng-click="print(centers)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span> Print All </a></li>
...

// what I would like to have
...
<li><a ng-click="print(filteredOrderedObject)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span> Print All </a></li>
...
// what I have
scope.print = function(ocw) {
   //printing
}

// what I would like to have
scope.print = function(filteredOrderedObject) {
   //printing
}
```

Comment: Filter your array manually.... `$filter('orderBy')(collection, expression, reverse, comparator)` and assign the result to a new array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `$filter` service directly in your code. Something like this.

```
var filtered = $filter('filter')(centers, subjectName);
filtered = $filter('orderBy')(filtered, ['name', 'parent']);
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: very kind! Great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use $eval to evaluate expression in controller.

Following is the syntax

```
$scope.centers = $scope.$eval("center in centers  | filter: subjectName | orderBy:[\'name\',\'parent']");
```